# React Native ScrollView scrollToBottom on load/navigate?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

In my React Native Expo app (running on iOS device) I have a `ScrollView` containing some `Text`. When the user navigates to this screen, it should already be showing the bottom of the `ScrollView`.

I tried using `useEffect` hook to call `scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated:False})` but it doesnt seem to scroll to the bottom when I navigate to the screen. The scrolling works only on hot-reloading the app.

```
  
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    "hello world",
    "hi there",
    "hey earth",
    "hola planet",
  ])

  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);  
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
  }, []);

  return(
    <View>
      <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <Text key={index}>{message}</Text>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect where the `ScrollView` is already scrolled to the bottom when the user navigates to this screen? This scrollToEnd action should only be done once, when the component has finished loading all the `Text` components. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are rendering a list of messages, it might be better to use `FlatList`, especially because it has a prop specifically for that -- `inverted`.

Note: [as hinted by the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#inverted), this uses a transform of scaleY -1 on the list (and then again on individual list to make them appear right side up). This means the refresh indicator also appears at the bottom, and you pull up from the bottom to trigger any refresh behaviour.

Usage is as simple as:

```
<FlatList inverted {...other props} />
```

Comment: Using `FlatList` sounds like a good idea, but can it be made to be scrolled all the way to the bottom of the list after the component is rendered?

Comment: @gameveloster this is where the `inverted` prop comes in. An `inverted` `FlatList` will render like in a typical messaging app: it starts at the bottom and you scroll _up_ to read older messages.